# How can i use Edit table primefaces correctly?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Hello I am trying to retrieve data from a database and modify it from the web interface
For the moment I manage to recover data but not to modify it .
Im using Edit table primefaces example :
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml?jfwid=ab3be
the example works well for me but I struggle doing the same using my own database

For the moment it displays the message "update has done" but the values ​​does not change

Here my code JSF:

```
public static void edit(Config f, int id){
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        DB_connection2 obj_DB_connection = new DB_connection2();
        connection = obj_DB_connection.get_connection();
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("update config set description=?,valeur=? where id='"+id+"");
        ps.setString(1, f.getDescription());
        ps.setInt(2, f.getValeur());
        ps.executeUpdate();
 }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


  public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent<Config> event) {
    Config f = new Config();
    f.setDescription(String.valueOf(event.getObject().getDescription()));
    f.setValeur((event.getObject().getValeur()));
    
    edit( f, event.getObject().getId());
     FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Update has done", String.valueOf(event.getObject().getId()));
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    
        
       
    }
```

Comment: Break down your problem in smaller problems. Are you sure your update query is working?

Comment: this is the smaller prob i can make there only a small table with 2 columns i cant do more , the query is working well

Comment: So the unclosed single quote is fine? If you call `edit` directly from `@PostConstruct` it is working?

Comment: The value doesn't change on db, on datatable or on both? Do you have any validation, required, etc?